# Spring boot default security enabled : Rest Service GET is working fine PUT and POST failing with 403 error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

For below code `getEmployees` Working fine with user name : "user" and password as generated by spring. But when I tried to POST/PUT an employee. I am getting 403 though same authorization working for GET.

```
package com.spring.boot.employee;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.spring.boot.employee.domain.Employee;
import com.spring.boot.employee.service.EmployeeService;

@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService employeeService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "addEmployee", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = { "application/json",
            "application/xml" }, produces = { "application/json" })
    public ResponseEntity<String> insertEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
        try {
            employeeService.insertEmployee(employee);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body("Empolyee inserted Suceessfully");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Empolyee inserted failed");
        }

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "getAllEmployees", method = RequestMethod.GET , produces = { "application/json" })
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployee() {
        return employeeService.getAllEmployees();
    }                 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Adding below security config class will resolve the issue.

package com.spring.boot.employee;

import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends
WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .csrf().disable();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Spring 4+, you need to deal with CSRF protection. This passes a token around to make sure that it's really the Javascript on your site that's doing the call.

You can either turn it off with a simple config entry, or you have to add a few small things to your app; both to your page and the javascript.

You can disable the csrf like below.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().
    authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").
    permitAll().and().logout().deleteCookies("rememberme").
    permitAll().and().rememberMe().tokenValiditySeconds(60);
}
```

Comment: Can you please let me know where we need to add this configuration.

Comment: thanks for the information about CSRF. Really helped me to resolve the issue